# Combine array of CSV's and keep one header with php

Tags: php, csv

I found a script here on Stack overflow that will merge several csv files into one csv but it won't keep one header. The csv's all have the same column count and all the headers are the same. How can the code be altered to keep the header of just one csv since their all the same?

```
<?php
   $files_to_merge = array("/csv1/results1.csv", "/csv2/results2.csv", "/csv3/results3.csv");
       $ftm = fopen("merged.csv","w+");
 foreach ($files_to_merge as $file){
     //loop through array
     $fh = fopen("csv/" .$file, "r");
     $line = false;

      while (($data = fgetcsv($fh,8192,",")) != FALSE){
          //ignore first line
          if (!$line){
             //ignore
            $line = TRUE;
          } else {
            fputcsv($ftm,$data,",");
       }
       //write content to new file
  }

fclose($fh);
echo($file . "-". $count . "\n");
//merge the records
endforeach;
fclose($ftm);  

?>
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do **NOT** mix the `:` alternate syntax with the standard `{` one. Especially when you don't even indent your code properly.

Comment: I would rewrite it using file() to read the data in and just pop the first item off the array (the headers) and add the following lines back to the file,

Comment: Thanks for that Marc I didn't even notice that.

Comment: I'll take a look at that approach Matt.